# How do I make it so that for the input Hello, the output would be e:1, h:1, l:2, o:1?

Tags: javascript

```html
<!doctype HTML>
<html>

<body>
  <h3>input</h3>
  <input id="myInput1" type="text">
  <button onclick="count()">See output</button> //I'd love it with a textbox as well, not with the console.

  <p id="output1"></p>

  <script>
    function count(string) {
      var string = document.getElementById("myInput1").value;
      return string.split("").reduce((a, letter) => {
        a[letter] = (a[letter] || 0) + 1;
        return a;
      }, {});
    }
    document.getElementById("output1").innerHTML = {};

    //I want the output to be in the paragraph above.

    // I want to make it so that the letters are put in order alphabetically matched with the number of times they occur.
  </script>
</body>

// Right now, it won't print out properly and I don't know why. If anyone has a solution or can help figure this out I would be extremely grateful.

</html>
```

Comment: What do you expect `innerHTML = {}` to do?

Comment: @Barmar I was expecting it to output the answer into output1. I suck at coding and that probably makes no sense. Do you have any ideas on how I can fix this?

Comment: Why would you expect assigning an empty object to output the answer? I already posted an answer, isn't that my idea of how you can fix it?

Comment: @Barmar I just saw your answer. You are a genius. Thank you for your help. I don't know what I was thinking to be honest, i'm really bad at this.

Comment: You weren't thinking. It's like cooking dinner in one pot, then putting an empty pot on the dinner table and expecting it to contain the dinner.

Comment: @Barmar that's a good analogy. I just realized that this isn't the solution because I need the output in alphabetical order. How would I do this?

Comment: @Barmar nevermind, I figured it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `JSON.stringify()` to convert an object to a string similar to the output you want.

You need to assign to the `innerHTML` inside the `count()` function, rather than returning the object.

`count()` doesn't need a parameter, it gets the string itself from the input value.

```js
function count() {
  var string = document.getElementById("myInput1").value;
  let counts = string.split("").reduce((a, letter) => {
    a[letter] = (a[letter] || 0) + 1;
    return a;
  }, {});
  document.getElementById("output1").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(counts);
}
```

```html
<h3>input</h3>
<input id="myInput1" type="text">
<button onclick="count()">See output</button>

<p id="output1"></p>
```